# CutsomKeyboard: EditText does not receive key press

Tags: android, android-edittext, custom-keyboard

I've been following [the Custom Keyboard example](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) to make the following:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.method.CharacterPickerDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * When an activity hosts a keyboardView, this class allows several EditText's to register for it.
 *
 * @author Maarten Pennings
 * @date   2012 December 23
 */
public class CustomKeyboard {
    private static final String TAG = "[CustomKeyboard]: ";

    /** A link to the KeyboardView that is used to render this CustomKeyboard. */
    private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
    /** A link to the activity that hosts the {@link #mKeyboardView}. */
    private Activity     mHostActivity;

    /** The key (code) handler. */
    private OnKeyboardActionListener mOnKeyboardActionListener = new OnKeyboardActionListener() {

        public final static int CodeDelete   = -5; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE
        public final static int CodeCancel   = -3; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_CANCEL
        public final static int CodePrev     = 55000;
        public final static int CodeAllLeft  = 55001;
        public final static int CodeLeft     = 55002;
        public final static int CodeRight    = 55003;
        public final static int CodeAllRight = 55004;
        public final static int CodeNext     = 55005;
        public final static int CodeClear    = 55006;

        @Override public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
            // NOTE We can say '<Key android:codes="49,50" ... >' in the xml file; all codes come in keyCodes, the first in this list in primaryCode
            // Get the EditText and its Editable
            View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
            if( focusCurrent==null || focusCurrent.getClass()!=EditText.class ) return;
            EditText edittext = (EditText) focusCurrent;
            Editable editable = edittext.getText();
            int start = edittext.getSelectionStart();
            Log.d(TAG,"Pressed");
            // Apply the key to the edittext
            if( primaryCode==CodeCancel ) {
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeDelete ) {
                if( editable!=null && start>0 ) editable.delete(start - 1, start);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeClear ) {
                if( editable!=null ) editable.clear();
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeLeft ) {
                if( start>0 ) edittext.setSelection(start - 1);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeRight ) {
                if (start < edittext.length()) edittext.setSelection(start + 1);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeAllLeft ) {
                edittext.setSelection(0);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeAllRight ) {
                edittext.setSelection(edittext.length());
            } else if( primaryCode==CodePrev ) {
                View focusNew= edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_LEFT);
                if( focusNew!=null ) focusNew.requestFocus();
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeNext ) {
                View focusNew= edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                if( focusNew!=null ) focusNew.requestFocus();
            } else { // insert character
                editable.insert(start, Character.toString((char) primaryCode));
                Log.d(TAG,"INPUT is this: "+Character.toString((char)primaryCode));
            }
        }

        @Override public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
            // NOTE We can say '<Key android:codes="49,50" ... >' in the xml file; all codes come in keyCodes, the first in this list in primaryCode
            // Get the EditText and its Editable
            View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
            if( focusCurrent==null || focusCurrent.getClass()!=EditText.class ) return;
            EditText edittext = (EditText) focusCurrent;
            Editable editable = edittext.getText();
            int start = edittext.getSelectionStart();
            Log.d(TAG,"Pressed");
            // Apply the key to the edittext
            if( primaryCode==CodeCancel ) {
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeDelete ) {
                if( editable!=null && start>0 ) editable.delete(start - 1, start);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeClear ) {
                if( editable!=null ) editable.clear();
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeLeft ) {
                if( start>0 ) edittext.setSelection(start - 1);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeRight ) {
                if (start < edittext.length()) edittext.setSelection(start + 1);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeAllLeft ) {
                edittext.setSelection(0);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeAllRight ) {
                edittext.setSelection(edittext.length());
            } else if( primaryCode==CodePrev ) {
                View focusNew= edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_LEFT);
                if( focusNew!=null ) focusNew.requestFocus();
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeNext ) {
                View focusNew= edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                if( focusNew!=null ) focusNew.requestFocus();
            } else { // insert character
                editable.insert(start, Character.toString((char) primaryCode));
                Log.d(TAG,"INPUT is this: "+Character.toString((char)primaryCode));
            }
        }

        @Override public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
        }

        @Override public void onText(CharSequence text) {
        }

        @Override public void swipeDown() {
        }

        @Override public void swipeLeft() {
        }

        @Override public void swipeRight() {
        }

        @Override public void swipeUp() {
        }
    };

    /**
     * Create a custom keyboard, that uses the KeyboardView (with resource id <var>viewid</var>) of the <var>host</var> activity,
     * and load the keyboard layout from xml file <var>layoutid</var> (see {@link Keyboard} for description).
     * Note that the <var>host</var> activity must have a <var>KeyboardView</var> in its layout (typically aligned with the bottom of the activity).
     * Note that the keyboard layout xml file may include key codes for navigation; see the constants in this class for their values.
     * Note that to enable EditText's to use this custom keyboard, call the {@link #registerEditText(int)}.
     *
     * @param host The hosting activity.
     * @param viewid The id of the KeyboardView.
     * @param layoutid The id of the xml file containing the keyboard layout.
     */
    public CustomKeyboard(Activity host, int viewid, int layoutid) {
        mHostActivity= host;
        mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
        // Hide the standard keyboard initially
        mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    /** Returns whether the CustomKeyboard is visible. */
    public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
        return mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    /** Make the CustomKeyboard visible, and hide the system keyboard for view v. */
    public void showCustomKeyboard( View v ) {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);
        if( v!=null ) ((InputMethodManager)mHostActivity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    /** Make the CustomKeyboard invisible. */
    public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(false);
    }

    /**
     * Register <var>EditText<var> with resource id <var>resid</var> (on the hosting activity) for using this custom keyboard.
     *
     * @param resid The resource id of the EditText that registers to the custom keyboard.
     */
    public void registerEditText(int resid) {
        // Find the EditText 'resid'
        EditText edittext= (EditText)mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);
        // Make the custom keyboard appear
        edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on focus listener, we can show the custom keyboard when the edit box gets focus, but also hide it when the edit box loses focus
            @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if( hasFocus ) showCustomKeyboard(v); else hideCustomKeyboard();
            }
        });
        edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on click listener, we can show the custom keyboard again, by tapping on an edit box that already had focus (but that had the keyboard hidden).
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
            }
        });
        // Disable standard keyboard hard way
        // NOTE There is also an easy way: 'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)' (but you will not have a cursor, and no 'edittext.setCursorVisible(true)' doesn't work )
        edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                EditText edittext = (EditText) v;
                int inType = edittext.getInputType();       // Backup the input type
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard keyboard
                edittext.onTouchEvent(event);               // Call native handler
                edittext.setInputType(inType);              // Restore input type
                return true; // Consume touch event
            }
        });
        // Disable spell check (hex strings look like words to Android)
        edittext.setInputType(edittext.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

}


// NOTE How can we change the background color of some keys (like the shift/ctrl/alt)?
// NOTE What does android:keyEdgeFlags do/mean
```

with MainActivity containing the following:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static String TAG = "[MainActivity]:";
    EditText expressionEditText;
    CustomKeyboard mCustomKeyboard;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mCustomKeyboard = new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.calculatorkbd);
        Log.d(TAG,"Init the keyboard");
        expressionEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.expressionEditText);
        Log.d(TAG,"Found the EditText");
        mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.expressionEditText);
        Log.d(TAG,"Registered with the keyboard");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if( mCustomKeyboard.isCustomKeyboardVisible() )
            mCustomKeyboard.hideCustomKeyboard();
        else this.finish();
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is when I press a key on the custom keyboard, the cursor in the EditText is not moving, and the EditText itself is empty. I've read somewhere here that manufacturers are no longer required to propagate such events, or something to that effect. Is that the problem in my case? If not, what *is*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux was in the line `focusCurrent.getClass()!=EditText.class`
As it turns out, the class is something like `AppCompatEditText`.
I remember someone at SO issuing a warning about this in comments. Now everything works.